In a header containing a table, how is one column appearing below the horizontal bar?
The following code defines a header with a logo, a course title, an quiz title, and boxes for the student to enter in their name, id and section.
I will comment out the image since it works and does not affect the answer.
How does "quiz title" end up below the horizontal line?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ans}{O{} O{36}}{%
  \fbox{\makebox(#2 pt,18pt){}}
}

% Define the quiz environment
\newenvironment{quiz}[2][]{%
\begin{flushleft}
  \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
    \multirow{2}{*}{
%\includegraphics[width=40pt]{rulogo.png}
}    &   &    & \small{Name} & \small{NetID} & \small{Section} \\
         & #1 & #2 & \ans[][162] & \ans[][50] & \ans \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{flushleft}
\hrule
}{%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{quiz}{mycourse}{quiz title}

\end{quiz}
\end{document}

The same thing happens if I just create a single line of output. I could understand if the line overflowed and the last item spilled onto the next line, but how does #2 jump out of the middle?
\begin{flushleft}
  \includegraphics[width=1cm]{logo.png} #1 #2 \ans[][144] \ans[][50] \ans \\
\end{flushleft}


unrelated, but size commands do not take an argument, use \small Name not \small{Name}

why is \ans defined with an optional argument that is never used?

You use two mandatory arguments in \begin{quiz}{mycourse}{quiz title}. So you want to define it as \newenvironment{quiz}[2]{...} instead of \newenvironment{quiz}[2][]{...}. Otherwise latex will look for an optional argument and treat the second {...} as part of the environment body.
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ans}{O{} O{36}}{%
  \fbox{\makebox(#2 pt,18pt){}}
}

% Define the quiz environment
\newenvironment{quiz}[2]{%
\begin{flushleft}
  \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
    \multirow{2}{*}{
\includegraphics[width=40pt]{example-image-duck}
}    &   &    & \small Name & \small NetID & \small Section \\
         & #1 & #2 & \ans[][162] & \ans[][50] & \ans \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{flushleft}
\hrule
}{%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{quiz}{mycourse}{quiz title}

\end{quiz}
\end{document}


